# SSL通信時、アドレスバーが緑にならない

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, https

ロリポップで独自SSLを契約し、URLをhttpsに変更しましたが、アドレスバーが緑になりません。 表示は問題できていますか、白い紙の表示になっています。

調べたところ、

> dummty.co.jp への接続は古い暗号スイートにより暗号化されています。
>   加えて、このページには安全でない他のリソースが含まれています。このリソースは送信中に他のユーザーから見られる可能性があります。また、悪意のあるユーザーによって改変されページの見た目が変わる可能性もあります。
>
> この接続には TLS 1.0 を使用しています。
>
> この接続は AES_256_CBC で暗号化されており、メッセージ認証には HMAC-SHA1、鍵交換メカニズムには DHE_RSA
>   が使用されています。
>
> このサーバーでは TLS の再交渉拡張がサポートされていません。

とメッセージが出ておりました。 緑色にするには、ロリポップ内で何か設定変更は必要でしょうか。

Comment: [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/22539)の方では解決済みになっているようですが、[混在コンテンツ](https://support.mozilla.org/ja/kb/mixed-content-blocking-firefox)の問題であった、ということで良いのでしょうか

Answer (score 6):

Google Chrome で以下のような表示になっている、と仮定してお答えします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

質問に書かれたメッセージに、安全でないリソースが含まれていると書かれていますよね。これは ページ自体は HTTPS で読み込まれているのに、一部のリソースがHTTP で読み込まれている、という意味です。URL が `http://` で始まる画像やスクリプトを読み込んでいないか、確認してみてください。

<sub>HTTP で読み込まれるリソースについては暗号化も接続先の検証も行われないため、ヘッダ情報を通してアクセス元のURLやアクセス先のURLが盗聴されたり、あるいは読み込んでいるリソースが改ざんされる恐れがあります。サイトは HTTPS で安全だと謳っているにもかかわらず、です。このため、ブラウザ側でそのことを示しているのです。</sub>

---

なお、take88 さんが書かれている EV SSL では、緑色の鍵アイコンに加えて企業名が表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そうではなく、以下の緑色の鍵アイコンだけであれば、ドメイン認証SSLでも構いません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

残念ながら ロリポップ以外の証明機関からEV SSL 証明書を取得する必要があると思います。

アドレスバーが緑になるのは EV SSL 証明書の場合のみで その他の証明書の種類だと緑にはなりません。 [ロリポップの独自SSL](https://lolipop.jp/manual/user/ssl-original/) を見ると次のように書いてあり「GMOグローバルサインのクイック認証SSL」という証明書のようです。

> 「ロリポップ！で提供する独自SSLは、GMOグローバルサイン株式会社のクイック認証SSLを利用しています。」

GMOグローバルサインの[SSLサーバ証明書の種類](https://jp.globalsign.com/service/ssl/knowledge/types-of-ssl.html) をみると「ドメイン認証」であって「EV SSL 証明」ではない事がわかります。

Answer (score 2):

chrome のアドレスバーの左端のアイコンはサーバー証明書と chrome のポリシーによって変わります。
今日付けの chrome のバージョンは 47.0.2526.80m ですが、このバージョンについていえば
- http つまり非暗号化のとき、紙アイコン
- サーバ証明書が sha1 署名のとき、紙アイコン（もはや安全ではないよ、と主張しています）
- サーバ証明書が sha2 署名のとき 緑の錠前アイコン
- EV SSL 証明書のとき、緑の錠前＋企業名
- http/https 混在のとき、<del>黄色の△つき錠前アイコン</del>紙アイコン
- 明らかに危険なとき、赤の×つき錠前アイコン（証明書の運用が間違っている、真に詐欺サイトなど）

※鍵と錠前は区別してください。

古い chrome の場合 sha1 署名のサーバ証明書も緑の錠前アイコンに表示していました。
最近のバージョンではポリシー変更がされたので紙アイコンになっています。

そのため今のバージョンの chrome で緑の錠前アイコンを出したいのであれば
「証明書を sha2 にて取得しなおす」が答えになると思います。
（中間認証局についても注意が必要です）

詳しい話がまとまっていると思うので
http://blog.livedoor.jp/k_urushima/archives/1750289.html

sha1 署名証明書をやめて sha2 署名証明書にするということは旧来機器を切り捨てるということでもあります。
sha2 署名証明書に対応していない機器はたとえば
- ガラケー
- Windows XP
- その他の組み込み系機器
が挙げられそうです。
パソコンで見ることだけを想定しているページなら sha2 署名証明書にしちゃって問題ないですが
ガラケーで見るユーザのほうが多いとかなら切り替えできないかも・・・
Windows XP ユーザって今どれくらいいるんでしょ？

Comment: 昨年9月の時点ではそのようなリリースが出ていましたし、実際△付き錠前も見かけていたのですが、現在 47.0.2526.80m および 49.0.2591.0 canary で確認すると、混在コンテンツも紙アイコンになっているように思います。 例：https://jsfiddle.net/72vt49zx/1/ → http://i.stack.imgur.com/eEYjb.png

Comment: その辺の仕様変更を勝手にやられると困っちゃいますね・・・ ページ本文は https で提供しているのに、勝手に組み込まれる広告が http だと紙アイコン表示になって何がなんだかわからないことに・・・

Comment: （上記仕様変更に関する記事 http://news.mynavi.jp/news/2015/10/18/086/ ）

Answer (score 0):

[テストツール](https://www.digicert.com/help/)を使うと原因がわかりますよ。